# How to convert cox regression output into a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, cox-regression

I ran univariate cox regression model using following code.

```
res <- coxph(Surv(DFS, DFS.Event) ~ Grade, data = Grade)
summary(res)
```

It output as follows:

```
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(DFS, DFS.Event) ~ Grade, data = Grade)

  n= 172, number of events= 38 
   (12 observations deleted due to missingness)

             coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)
GradeGrade2 1.153     3.167    1.026 1.123    0.261
GradeGrade3 1.006     2.736    1.028 0.979    0.327

            exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
GradeGrade2     3.167     0.3158    0.4237     23.67
GradeGrade3     2.736     0.3655    0.3651     20.50

Concordance= 0.539  (se = 0.04 )
Likelihood ratio test= 1.82  on 2 df,   p=0.4
Wald test            = 1.34  on 2 df,   p=0.5
Score (logrank) test = 1.45  on 2 df,   p=0.5
```

I want to convert the output into a dataframe. My expected output is:

```
Variable    coef    exp(coef)   se(coef)    z   p   lower 0.95  upper 0.95
GradeGrade2 1.153   3.167   1.026   1.123   0.261   0.4237  23.67
GradeGrade3 1.006   2.736   1.028   0.979   0.327   0.3651  20.5
```

Comment: The `broom` package's `tidy` method should do the trick.

Comment: That is not the print output of coxph. It’s the output of its associated summary method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are looking for a method to extract information from output of `summary(coxph(something))`, I recommend a self-written function of the form

```r
CoxphToDF <- function(y) {
  stopifnot(class(y) == "summary.coxph")
  
  y <- 
    cbind(y[["coefficients"]], 
          `lower .95` = y[["conf.int"]][, "lower .95"], 
          `upper .95` = y[["conf.int"]][, "upper .95"]
    )
  
  cbind(Variable = rownames(y), as.data.frame(y))  
}
```

Toy data from `?coxph`:

```
library(survival)

test2 <- list(start=c(1,2,5,2,1,7,3,4,8,8), 
              stop=c(2,3,6,7,8,9,9,9,14,17), 
              event=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0), 
              x=c(1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0)) 
bladder1 <- bladder[bladder$enum < 5, ] 

testobject <- summary(coxph(Surv(stop, event) ~ (rx + size + number) * strata(enum),
                            cluster = id, bladder1))
```

The result looks odd as the row names are identical to the `Variable` column, but this mimics the expectations.

```
CoxphToDF(testobject) |> head()
#>                                    Variable        coef exp(coef)   se(coef)
#> rx                                       rx -0.52598436 0.5909733 0.31582587
#> size                                   size  0.06961334 1.0720936 0.10155903
#> number                               number  0.23817961 1.2689371 0.07588471
#> rx:strata(enum)enum=2 rx:strata(enum)enum=2 -0.10632654 0.8991310 0.50423983
#> rx:strata(enum)enum=3 rx:strata(enum)enum=3 -0.17250719 0.8415522 0.55780009
#> rx:strata(enum)enum=4 rx:strata(enum)enum=4 -0.10945460 0.8963229 0.65730033
#>                        robust se          z    Pr(>|z|) lower .95 upper .95
#> rx                    0.31523946 -1.6685232 0.095211902 0.3185925  1.096226
#> size                  0.08863123  0.7854268 0.432203369 0.9011346  1.275486
#> number                0.07458532  3.1933847 0.001406155 1.0963594  1.468680
#> rx:strata(enum)enum=2 0.33395783 -0.3183831 0.750194332 0.4672589  1.730168
#> rx:strata(enum)enum=3 0.39867743 -0.4326987 0.665233705 0.3852354  1.838383
#> rx:strata(enum)enum=4 0.50636317 -0.2161583 0.828864362 0.3322365  2.418141
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: `lower 0.95`  and  `upper 0.95` on both the lines are same. I am supposed to get `0.4237`    and `23.67` in line one and `0.3651`     `20.50` in line two. But I am getting same values at both the lines